# Spring Rest Controller return 406 NOT acceptable for text/plain

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a problem with rest controller and text/plain. I have read many answers here and tried lot of Solutions without success. I have a rest controller that should return a String as text/plain. Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/content", headers="Accept=*/*",  
produces={"text/plain", "application/json"})
public class MyController {

@GetMapping(value = "", produces = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> getContent() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("a,b,c\n1,2,3\n3,4,5");
}
```

so when i make a call like this:

```
https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/content -H "accept: text/plain"
```

I get 406 Not Acceptable Response with message: Could not find acceptable representation

But with:

```
https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/content -H "accept: application/json"
```

i got the excepted result with:

```
content-type: text/plain
```

in the Response Header.

I tried to adjust  the ContenNegociationManager in my WebMvcConfigurationSupport like this:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
{
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
            favorParameter(false).
            parameterName("mediaType").
            ignoreAcceptHeader(false).
            useJaf(false).
            defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            mediaType("properties", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
}
```

I also tried with:

```
mediaType("plain", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

and I still get the same Response 406.

My Converter List is defined as:

```
<util:list id="myConverters">
    <ref bean="customJsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <ref bean="customXmlHttpMessageConverter"/>
</util:list>

<bean id="customJsonHttpMessageConverter" parent="jsonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="jaxbContextFactory" ref="customJaxbContextFactory" />
</bean>
    
<bean id="customXmlHttpMessageConverter" parent="xmlHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="jaxbContextFactory" ref="customJaxbContextFactory" />
</bean>
```

and in the Configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
{
    converters.addAll(myConverters);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you check your `ObjectMapper` config ? Does `StringHttpMessageConverter` is well defined inside ?

Comment: i didnt configured it. I have no config for

Comment: I think this is a config problem. If your spring is correct configured you cant reproduce this issue. Im missing some conig this why i get this error

Comment: In My WebMvcConfigurationSupport i have  @Resource
 private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> myConverters;

Comment: Consider looking at `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters` and adding all the remaining converters as well.

Comment: i solved it by adding the StringHttpMessageConverter to the MessageConverters. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @CodeScale  for the hint. I fixed it by adding the StringHttpMessageConverter to my Converters.

```
@Override
protected void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
{
    myConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.addAll(myConverters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated my answer and question. But when i remove messageConvertersV2.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter()); i get the same issue